# How can we change grand total when payment method is cash on delivery using Magento 1.8?

Tags: magento-1.8, checkout, grand-total

How can we round up or down grand totals when payment method is cash on delivery on checkout page.
ex. If total is 50.60 then if customer selected cash on delivery payment method then grand total should be 51.00.

How can we do that please help it will be very useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try use event observer.

config.xml

```
<events>
    <payment_method_is_active>
        <observers>
            <namespace_module>
                <type>singleton</type>
                <class>NamaSpace_Module_Model_Observer</class>
                <method>paymentmethod</method>
            </namespace_module>
        </observers>
    </payment_method_is_active>
</events>
```

observer.php

```
<?php 
class NamaSpace_Module_Model_Observer{
    public function paymentmethod(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) 
    {
        $method = $observer->getEvent()->getMethodInstance();
        $quote = $observer->getEvent()->getQuote();
        if($method->getCode()=='COD')
        {
            //get grand total and modified it.
        }

    } 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the PHP function `round()` to round off the price.

Example is below:

```
echo round(3.5); output: 4
```

Comment: Welcome to Magento SE. Changing the output and then still charge the original price is certainly not what OP wanted, so unfortunately this answer is not very helpful